# Accessing Api with Javascript using Oauth

Tags: javascript, cakephp, backbone.js, oauth, oauth-2.0

Having issues accessing data from my api once i have created a access token with a simple javascript client.

Here is my Js app object, as you can see i return a new access_token from my api - this works fine up to this point. I store the access_token into app.AccessToken for me to use in any other api calls i make throughout the app. But for some reason when i request anything the response is always the login page, so basically i am getting redirected when i try access anything even though i passing over a working in-date access_token.

```
var app = (function(){

/**
 * Api
 * @type Object
 */
var api = {
    AccessToken : null,
    views: {},
    models: {},
    collections: {},
    content: null,
    router: null,
    documents: null,
    init: function() {
        this.content = $("#content");
        this.documents = new api.collections.Documents();
        Backbone.history.start();
        return this;
    },
    changeContent: function(el) {
        this.content.empty().append(el);
        return this;
    },
    title: function(str) {
        // set page title 
    }
};

/**
 * ViewFactory
 * @type Object
 */
var ViewFactory = {
    documents: function() {
        this.documentsView = new api.views.documents({
            model: api.documents
        });
        return this.documentsView;
    }
};

/**
 * AppRouter
 * @type Object
 */
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '' : 'documents'
    },
    documents: function() {
        var view = ViewFactory.documents();
        api.changeContent(view.$el);
        view.render();
    }
});

/**
 * OAuth
 * @type Object
 * @return string  
 */
var OAuth = {

    title    : 'Js Client',
    clientId : 'NTUxNTY4YWE1NWUxMzI4',
    username : 'john@globallcoach.com',
    password : 'password',

    init: function() {
        var provision = OAuth.provision();
        if(provision.hasOwnProperty('success')) {
            var authenticate = OAuth.authenticate();
            if(authenticate.hasOwnProperty('access_token')) {
                api.AccessToken = authenticate['access_token'];
            }
        }
    },

    provision: function() {
        var response;
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url  : 'http://customer-server-2.dev/oauth/provision/.json', 
            type : 'get',
            data : {
                title : OAuth.title,
                client_id : OAuth.clientId
            },
            success:function(data) {
                response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            }, 
        });
        return response;
    },

    authenticate: function() {
        var response;
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url  : 'http://customer-server-2.dev/oauth/token.json', 
            type : 'get',
            data : {
                'grant_type' : 'password',
                'username'   : OAuth.username,
                'password'   : OAuth.password,
                'client_id'  : OAuth.clientId,
            },
            success:function(data) {
                response = data;
            }
        });
        return response;
    },
}

/**
 * Exercute & return
 */
api.router = new Router();
OAuth.init();
return api;

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I needed to make sure that on the Rest AppController i needed to defined `$this->Auth->allow()` on the actions within the api scope.